# The class or file does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I'm receiving this error: `The class or file does not exist`. I have put my `.ttf` file in the folder `resources/font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf` but receive an error when I register the new font.

```
    public static void registerFont() {
    try {

        if(!FontFactory.isRegistered("SourceSansPro"))
        {
            
            URL pathFont = GeneradorMinuta.class.getClassLoader().getResource("font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
            FontFactory.register(pathFont.toString(), "SourceSansPro");       
            //FontFactory.register("font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", "SourceSansPro");      
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
    
    catFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 12, Font.BOLD);
    redFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 11, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    greenFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 18, Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(8, 111, 50));
    subFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 12, Font.BOLD);
    smallBold = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 12, Font.BOLD);
    bodyFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 10);
    underlinedFont = FontFactory.getFont("SourceSansPro", 10, Font.UNDERLINE);
}
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Table 'name'
does not exist in
file:/C:/Desarrollo/Software/Workspace/WorkspaceResuelve/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/intr_resuelve/beadep/base_domainResuelve/intr_resuelve/WEB-INF/classes/font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.getBaseFont(TrueTypeFont.java:672)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:834)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:499)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(BaseFont.java:1233)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp.register(FontFactoryImp.java:452)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.register(FontFactory.java:341)
    at es.ja.csalud.sas.intranet.ventanillatramitacion.portaFirma.business.GeneradorMinuta.registerFont(GeneradorMinuta.java:94)
    at es.ja.csalud.sas.intranet.ventanillatramitacion.portaFirma.business.GeneradorMinuta.generarDocumentoMinuta(GeneradorMinuta.java:113)
    at es.ja.csalud.sas.intranet.ventanillatramitacion.portaFirma.aries.EnviarRegistro.registrarFichero(EnviarRegistro.java:149)
    at es.ja.csalud.sas.intranet.ventanillatramitacion.expediente.presentation.boundary.ExpedientesReclamacionesBean.enviarARegistro(ExpedientesReclamacionesBean.java:3554)
    at es.ja.csalud.sas.intranet.ventanillatramitacion.expediente.presentation.boundary.ExpedientesReclamacionesBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.enviarARegistro(ExpedientesReclamacionesBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:780)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:529)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` this is a bad way of logging errors. Print the whole stack trace. You are throwing away valuable information.

Comment: ok I change it, now going to show whole stack trace. Few minuts please.

Comment: do you get this error from maven or from IDE? if latter - check which extensions does your IDE interpret as resources

Comment: From IDe iterpret, how can check witch extension resources mi IDE knows?

Comment: See? The exception is much clearer than what you posted originally. It **can** find the font file. The problem is that it's expecting the font to contain a [name table](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html) which apparently doesn't exist. I would say that the font file you are using is basically corrupt or at least considering invalid by this library.

Comment: This means that source sans pro is not compatible with my project in java using jersey and jpa?there is any similar font to install in my project?